# Petting an unredeemed firstborn donkey ("Peter Chamor")

Tags: halacha, animals, bechor-firstborn, hanaah-benefit, issurei-hanaa

The Talmud ([Bekhoroth 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bekhorot.9b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)) cites the opinion of Rabbi Yehuda that it is forbidden to derive benefit from a firstborn donkey before it is redeemed.  This view is codified by the [Rambam (Bikkurim 12:4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=7383) and the [Shulchan Aruch (YD 321:8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.321.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).  This prohibition includes benefitting from the animal's work, shearings, or money from its sale.

Considering that donkey foals possess a fair amount of charm, would this prohibition preclude deriving any pleasure prior to the redemption by, e.g., entertaining children, patting it, and/or viewing it for reasons not essential to the performance of the *mitzvah*?

[image: Redemption of Firstborn Donkey]

Comment: If you couldn't see it why would everyone bring it to the ceremony? Or alternatively how could you know where to swing your ax to chop it's head off?

Comment: @DoubleAA מצוות לאו ליהנות ניתנו - I asking about nonessential viewing, e.g. as an attraction prior ro performing the mitzvah. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: מצוות לאו להנות ניתנו May be that is not an isur but a permission to use shofar asur behanaa

Comment: @kouty That was my point - the viewing that is essential to performing the mitzvah should be permitted even if nonessential viewing is forbidden.  So DoubleAA's question doesn't really stand.

Comment: @Loewian You never need to see the donkey to redeem it.

Comment: Why would these cases be any different than the ones listed in the ramba”m? @Loewian

Comment: I've never heard of a prohibition on staring at a cheeseburger. Indeed some Rishonim recommend staring at it and salivating and still deciding not to eat it.

Comment: @DoubleAA לא שמעת אינו ראיה assuming one is נהנה from staring at a cheeseburger.  If you can present rishonim that view that as הנאה I would accept that as a partial answer.  In contrast, see e.g...

Comment: https://www.toraland.org.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%A2-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%99/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%94/

Comment: @Loani Assuming you mean as opposed to tangible benefits, see e.g. the discussion by *orlah* here: https://www.toraland.org.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%A2-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%99/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%94/ (which indeed suggests that intangible benefit should also be out).

Comment: @DoubleAA Presumably, one could draw a distinction between incidentally seeing an animal, without any intention for enjoyment, vs. going to specifically see it, out of intellectual curiosity, to entertain the kids, etc.  A good answer should be able to explore this distinction.

Comment: Ugh. Petter in context implies someone who pets things, but changing it to Peter makes it look like the pet's name is Peter. I think the pun might be too confusing for people who haven't opened the post: they expect a question about petting a petter, and end up seeing a question about petting a פטר.

Answer (score 5):

I attended a *pidyon petter chamor* in Pittsburgh in 2017.  It was organized by the Kollel and attended by many of the local Orthodox rabbis (and lots of other people).  Unfortunately the web site they set up at the time is no longer there (and not in the Wayback Machine), but I have a video (linked on my [blog post about the event](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2017/09/27/pidyon-petter-chamor.html)).

In the (first, introductory) video, Rabbi Avrohom Weisswasser reported the research they did, but unfortunately didn't cite a source:

> He has the *halachos* of a holy animal.  We're not allowed to work him until after the redemption.  We're not allowed to play with him, unless we're doing it for *his* good.  And we were told -- there's a dispute about this, but we were told we can't even dress him up, besides a blanket. (0:21-0:50)

A little later (1:27) he says he consulted Rabbi Ariel Shoshan of Scottsdale, AZ, who had done this *mitzvah* previously.  Whether R' Shoshan is the source of the information quoted above, I do not know.

In the video, during the introductory comments, you can see many children gathered around the donkey, but they're not petting him -- the handler is keeping him away from them.  (After, the handler allowed plenty of petting.)

Before the event I had some questions about the logistics of the *kinyan* (they were selling shares of the donkey so that more people could participate), and they also mentioned consulting [Rabbi Shlomo Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Miller) of Toronto.

Comment: +1 interesting. in the photo i posted as well as a *peter* I attended, they definitely dolled the donkey up good.

Comment: @Loewian I've seen pictures where the donkey is more decorated, too.  He did say there's a dispute.  Ours had a decorated blanket.